# Creating a CLI application with root access

Tags: c++, centos

I am developing a php application which serves as a GUI for a seever side application. Because of the nature of the application, it needs to run exec commands which require  root privileges. (things like restarting a service). I was able to get around it by giving nginx sudo access to specific commands. But it still requires a few functions which will be easy to make with a CLI.

Now the problem I am facing is starting this application from php with arguments as root. This is how I launch my app,

`path/application - e "command I want"`

The web app will be only one installed on the server (kind of like a control panel). Should I focus on making a service instead of an application? If I do make an service how would I let php contact it? I have developed windows applications in the past using .NET and c++.

I did look at dotnet core to make a Linux service, but I don't think it'll be what I need. Can I have any suggestions? All I need the app to have is root access, possibly without sudo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could the application be a setuid root application?  Please test it for security before doing so

```
chown root /path/to/binary
chmod u+s /path/to/binary
```

Comment: well if this could execute the application as root, then I will just make a whitelist of commands within the application (specific commands) so only they can run. I don't have much knowledge with linux, so I will try this method and let you know.

Comment: This method works. Optionally you can also set `setuid(0)` within the main function in c++. Though it works without that in my case.  I have coded my c++ app with hardcoded commands that can be accessed via arguments.. this way the apps wont be able to do much damage. Only disadvantage is that the app will require updating when a new function is needed.